# Why is an empty XML node xml datatype not being recognized in this query?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

My query seems to not recognize self-closing or empty nodes at all. Shouldn't the empty `<td/>` node return 'null'? Or an empty string. Even if I place an empty space in the node, it still is ignored.

```
declare @x xml; 

    set @x='<root>
                <tr>
                    <td />
                    <td>sdfg</td>
                    <td>dfgh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>foo</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>poo</td>
                </tr>
            </root>'
select
    x.c.value('(td//text())[1]', 'varchar(1024)') as col1
    ,x.c.value('(td//text())[2]', 'varchar(1024)') as col2
    ,x.c.value('(td//text())[3]', 'varchar(1024)') as col3
from @x.nodes('/root/tr') x(c)
```

I want the result to be this:

```
col1 col2 col3
null sdfg dfgh
foo  bar  poo
```

..but instead I get this:

```
col1 col2 col3
sdfg dfgh null
foo  bar  poo
```

Answer (score 4):

In `(td//text())[1]` the predicate `[1]` will return the first node returned by the XQuery `(td//text())`.

You are saying that you want the first `text()` node. But in the first `td` element there are no text nodes present so you get the text node for the second `td` element which is the first text node returned.

You need to specify the position predicate on the `td` node instead.

This will give you `null` in `col1`

```
select
     x.c.value('td[1]/text()[1]', 'varchar(1024)') as col1
    ,x.c.value('td[2]/text()[1]', 'varchar(1024)') as col2
    ,x.c.value('td[3]/text()[1]', 'varchar(1024)') as col3
from @x.nodes('/root/tr') x(c)
```

And not specifying the text() node will give you an empty string in `col1`.

```
select
     x.c.value('td[1]', 'varchar(1024)') as col1
    ,x.c.value('td[2]', 'varchar(1024)') as col2
    ,x.c.value('td[3]', 'varchar(1024)') as col3
from @x.nodes('/root/tr') x(c)
```